# Manejo de errores con JSONIFY

Tags: python, mongodb, validación, flask

Estoy teniendo un problema mostrando errores al usuario. Lo que quiero hacer es por medio de AJAX mostrarle un error en un

que viene desde las validaciones, aqui tienen un ejemplo del codigo.

HTML:

```
<p class="error error--hidden"></p>
```

CSS:

```
.error--hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Js:

```
$("form[name=login_form]").submit(function (e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    var $error = $form.find(".error");
    var data = $form.serialize();
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user/login",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (resp) {
            window.location.href = "/";
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            if (xhr.status === 401) {
                $error.text(xhr.responseText).removeClass("error--hidden");
            } else {
                $error.text("Error al procesar la solicitud").removeClass("error--hidden");
            }
        }
    });

    function validarCorreo(correo) {
        var regex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
        return regex.test(correo);
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Python (Uso Flask):

```
# Verificar si el usuario existe y la contraseña coincide
if user and check_password_hash(user['contrasena'], password):
    session['logged_in'] = True
    session['user'] = user
    if user['rol'] == 'ADMIN':
        return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('user_dashboard'))
else:
    return jsonify({"error": "credenciales invalidas"}), 400
```

¿Cual es el error?

1. Envio el formulario vacio

[image]

2. Me muestra esta pantalla negra con la validacion cuando deberia de imprimir el error en la etiqueta

   para hacerlo legible al usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por su ayuda!